# Different margins for first and last page in iText PDF

Tags: java, itext

Is there a way to specify different margins for my first and last pages in iText?
I have a large header to be placed in first page and a large footer to be present in the last page.

The trouble is when I position the footer absolutely the content of the page might overlap it because of the absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

yes.
before creating last page, set margins and then call `newpage()` method of `Document` object.

Comment: and how will I know its the last page?

Comment: I don't know the layout of your document, this is up to you. The footer should stay alone in the last page or after the last line of content?

Comment: Actually the content is dynamic in size. So it may be 2 pages or 20 pages. But I've gotta make sure that the footer always appears in the last page only. So I was thinking if I can find out the last page and change its bottom margin only, without affecting the rest of the pages.

Comment: by now I'm not sure to fully understand your request. If the problem is only to not overlap footer with content, you may use the **getVerticalPosition** method of PdfWriter and correctly position your footer. There's no page margins involved in that.

Comment: Did it by calculating the available space in the PDF. If the space is less that the size of the footer height then I just add a new page and add the footer there.

Comment: No newPage() method for document in itextpdf 7. How can this implemented in version 7 ??