# itext 7 dynamic last page margin

Tags: .net, itext7

I'm working on a document renderer that has some fairly complex requirements.  The piece that I'm working on specifically right now, is the ability to have different margins on the last page, the first page, and each of the middle pages, where the length of a given document is unknown (First page could also have different margins as well) as it's driven by user input (to a point).

I've seen a few examples of where margins on different pages were done by using document.SetMargins(...) and document.NewPage() (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837680/different-margins-for-first-and-last-page-in-itext-pdf)).  The problem is I don't know when the last page will occur, there may be enough content for 1 page or 20.

I tried using page events to change the document margins in the page end events, which appeared to work for the header and footer tables (as the first, middle and last pages may have different headers / footers as well), but not the content of the last page.

Update: I adapted to use a custom renderer (overrode flush method shown below and main flow for the generation of a test pdf).  I'm not quite understanding what the areabreak for last page is supposed to do for this situation.  As I understand it, its used for switching between renderers (between multiple columns and a single column) and then add more content after switching renderers.  Where this situation is more like the resultRenderer.Move(x, y) example, but looking through the various methods, there doesn't seem to be a resize canvas option.

```
void Main()
{   
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(Dest));
    PageSize pageSize = PageSize.A4;
    Document doc = new Document(pdf, pageSize, false);
    HeaderHandler hh = new HeaderHandler(doc);
    DocumentRenderer renderer = new CustomRenderer(doc, hh);

    hh.First = new Margin(72f, 36f, 36f, 36f);
    hh.Last = new Margin (72f, 72f, 36f, 36f);
    hh.Middle = new Margin();

    doc.SetRenderer(renderer);

    pdf.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, hh);


    var elementList = new List<IElement>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i ++)
    {
        // adds various types of elements, both block and leaf elements
        AddItemToList(elementList, i);
    }

    foreach (var e in elementList)
    {
        var blockElement = e as IBlockElement;
        var leafElement = e as ILeafElement;

        if (blockElement != null)
        {
            doc.Add(blockElement);  
        }
        else if (leafElement != null) 
        {
            var para = new Paragraph();
            para.Add(leafElement);

            doc.Add(para);
        }
    }

    // go to the last page -- this seems like something that would be put in only after changing the style of a given set of content (between multiple columns and a single column 
    doc.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.LAST_PAGE));    

    // this causes all pages to use the HH Last Margin as thats the last margin to get set
    renderer.Flush();

    // without this it doesn't appear to use any of the margins defined in the renderer.
    doc.Relayout();
    doc.Close();
}

protected override void FlushSingleRenderer(IRenderer resultRenderer)
{       
    int pageNum = resultRenderer.GetOccupiedArea().GetPageNumber();
    Margin margin = new Margin();

    if (pageNum == 1)
    {
        margin.Top = HH.First.Top;
        margin.Right = HH.First.Right;
        margin.Bottom = HH.First.Bottom;
        margin.Left = HH.First.Left;
        //  doc.SetMargins(72 + hh.GetHeaderHeight(), 36, 36 + hh.GetFooterHeight(), 36);
    }
    else if (pageNum == document.GetPdfDocument().GetNumberOfPages())
    {
        margin.Top = HH.Last.Top;
        margin.Right = HH.Last.Right;
        margin.Bottom = HH.Last.Bottom;
        margin.Left = HH.Last.Left;
    }
    else 
    {
        margin.Top = HH.Middle.Top;
        margin.Right = HH.Middle.Right;
        margin.Bottom = HH.Middle.Bottom;
        margin.Left = HH.Middle.Left;
    }

    margin.Top += HH.GetHeaderHeight();
    margin.Bottom += HH.GetFooterHeight();

    base.document.SetMargins(margin.Top, margin.Right, margin.Bottom, margin.Left);
    base.FlushSingleRenderer(resultRenderer);
}
```

Other info that might be pertinent:

Right now I'm just using the document.Add(x) method to add a list block level elements to the document.

I adapted [this best question](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/page-events/itext7-why-does-my-header-overlap-my-content) to handle both the footer and header in the same page end event.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please go to [chapter 2 of the Building Blocks tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2), and scroll to the section **Flushing the Document renderer**. In that example, you can see how we change the document renderer of the last page so that the text shows a different behavior. That is the approach you'll have to follow.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in a direction @Bruno.  I updated the code block to reflect my new strategy, and feels like I'm getting closer, but there's still something missing.  Changing the renderer doesn't seem like it would do anything, as I don't have any content left to add after getting through all the elements with the new renderer.

Comment: I'm also looking at using the approach (as I may have to support multiple columns) to use a custom column renderer and resize the column when on the last page.  It looks like there are some unique challenges / edge scenarios where after resizing the last page the content no longer fits.   It doesn't look like changing the dimensions of the renderer is allowed however.